# Broken dropdown list at checkout in WooCommerce 2

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently upgraded to WC 2 and the dropdown lists have duplicated and are not clickable.

This is for both the Country and State dropdowns

[image: Duplicate dropdown list for country]

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by WooCommerce's [enhanced dropdown boxes](http://www.20milesnorth.com/blog/removing-enhanced-dropdown-boxes-in-woocommerce-checkout/) at checkout.

To fix this, add the following code to your **functions.php** file in your theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );

function agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'select2' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'select2');
        wp_deregister_script('select2');
    }
}
```